# What is a cone, possibly of polynomials?

Tags: optimization

I'm reading texts about optimization when given a set of polynomial constraints, like $f_1=\cdots=f_m=0$ and $q_1\ge 0,\ldots,q_\ell\ge 0$, over the reals.

I have encountered statements about "the cone" of a polynomial or a set of polynomials.

For example, sometimes the cone is defined to be the minimal set $C$ that contains a given collection $f_1,...,f_m$ of polynomials, such that if $g,h\in C$ then $g\cdot h\in C$, and $ag+bh\in C$, for $a,b$ *positive* scalars in $\mathbb{R}$. 
Here is an example use of the term cone that is undefined: [here](http://www.mit.edu/~parrilo/ecc03_course/06_positivstellensatz.pdf)

**Question**: What is a cone (in the context of polynomial equations, optimization and SDP)? What is $\operatorname{cone}(f)$ for $f$ a polynomial? And what is $\operatorname{cone}(S)$ for $S$ a set of polynomials?

Comment: Please cite your source.

Comment: It's likely that the author means "the conical hull of the set $S$", which is the set of all points $x$ such $x$ can be written as a linear combination of $k$ points $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $ldots$, $x_{k}$ $S$ with nonnegative coefficients in the linear combination.

Comment: There is no single source. It's multiple sources.

Comment: I don't think this is what they mean. I added an example.

Comment: @Jack Your example agrees with Brian's comment. Pretty sure the author is talking about the *conical hull*, i.e. the set of all [conical combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination) of the given vectors (which are polynomials in your case)

Comment: @M.Winter, hmm...maybe. But then, how come we can multiply by *polynomials* and not just by scalars?

Comment: @Jack You are right! This $g\cdot h\in C$ is strange. It would be very helpful to know the source of this example! Is there a chance you can give it?

Comment: Here, www.mit.edu/~parrilo/ecc03_course/06_positivstellensatz.pdf         He uses cone, but don't define it, since these are slides. He uses cone in two different settings, one I think as you did, and another as something about polynomial multiplication...

Comment: The definition of a cone in polynomial optimization is somewhat more general than the more commonly used (in other areas of convex optimization) definition of a cone.  Parillo's notes are pretty clear on this unusual definition: http://www.mit.edu/~parrilo/ecc03_course/03_algebra_and_duality.pdf

Comment: Now, given the definitions in part 3 of Parillo's notes, what is your question?

Comment: well, the question is whether there is a connection to other "cones" as you defined it? What is the meaning of such a cone? I.e., why is it called a cone?